# Postgresql connection marked as broken by Hikari

Tags: spring, postgresql, kotlin, jooq, hikaricp

I have Spring application that regularly inserts records in a PostgreSQL-DB. Now, after a scheduled set of imports is done it takes a few seconds until I get the following warning:

```
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection   : HikariPool-1 - Connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@7d18a7dc marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08006), ErrorCode(0)
```

followed by the this exception:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:335) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:143) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.execute(PgPreparedStatement.java:132) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.execute(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:44) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.execute(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.jooq.tools.jdbc.DefaultPreparedStatement.execute(DefaultPreparedStatement.java:209) ~[jooq-3.11.9.jar:na]
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:432) ~[jooq-3.11.9.jar:na]
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractDMLQuery.execute(AbstractDMLQuery.java:613) ~[jooq-3.11.9.jar:na]
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:350) ~[jooq-3.11.9.jar:na]
    at org.jooq.impl.Tools$10$1.block(Tools.java:4377) ~[jooq-3.11.9.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.managedBlock(ForkJoinPool.java:3118) ~[na:na]
    at org.jooq.impl.Tools$10.get(Tools.java:4374) ~[jooq-3.11.9.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1692) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:177) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: null
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.receiveChar(PGStream.java:308) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1952) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:308) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
```

On most occurrences this also sets my database in recovery mode.

On the next run of the scheduler the hikari pool warns about the connections that could not be validated:

```
HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@389c2816 (This connection has been closed.). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.
```

I fiddled around with the `validation-timeout` and `max-lifetime` settings of hikari but none of the changes seemed to have any effect.

Comment: What is the validation query you are using?

Comment: Except for url and credentials everything is set to default. Until now it worked well but now that I added the new schedule this behavior shows

Comment: How did you resolve the issue?

Comment: @fhueser We are seeing the exact same issue. Were you able to resolve it

Comment: @SurajMenon what postgresql and hikari version do you use? I don't get this behavior anymore and I suspect it was due to some upgrades...

Comment: @fhueser Facing same issue. I am using Spring Boot 2.1.7 RELEASE which actually uses 42.2.6 version of postgresql.

Comment: I have also the same problem!

Comment: Anyone got the solution for this issue?

Comment: Can you give more details? you configuration, drivers, is using hibernate/pgpool/pgbouncer?

Comment: what's your java version?

Comment: This looks similar: [HikariPool-1 - Connection marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08006), ErrorCode(0)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60925289/15862). Can you check if upgrading Java to 11.0.5 or later fixes the problem?

Comment: Could this be related to this reported possible bug in the JDBC driver?
https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/16473-67e89233f1976610%40postgresql.org

Comment: did you check the postgreSQL logs? It seems to me your DB is crashing for some issue

Comment: Consider using @DirtiesContext like they said there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59372048/testcontainers-hikari-and-failed-to-validate-connection-org-postgresql-jdbc-pgc
Suprisingly might help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to see the Connection Validation:

- Review HikariCP configuration in the Spring application.
- Try the `connection-test-query` property is set appropriately (e.g., `"SELECT 1"`).

```yaml
   spring:
     datasource:
       hikari:
         connection-test-query: SELECT 1
```

- Adjust settings in your application's requirements:

```yaml
      spring:
        datasource:
          hikari:
            connectionTimeout: 30000
            validationTimeout: 3000
            maxLifetime: 1800000
            maximumPoolSize: 10
```

Answer (score 0):

I had it same problem, when my DB was in docker, one of request took a lot of memory in my docker and oom kill it.

First you need check postgres log and you can find cause (if it is not oom)