# Artifactory connection to artifactory DB brakes on startup

Tags: artifactory

I'm not able to start artifactory server due to following error:

```
    2023-05-15T11:24:02.236Z [jfrt ] [WARN ] [4ab4344b0bc82a8 ] [c.z.h.p.ProxyConnection:182   ] [Catalina-utility-1  ] - HikariCP Main - Connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@3dbe8d4e marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08006), ErrorCode(0)
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:335)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:143)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:120)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
        at org.jfrog.storage.JdbcHelper.executeUpdate(JdbcHelper.java:205)
        at org.artifactory.storage.db.servers.dao.ArtifactoryServersDao.updateArtifactoryServer(ArtifactoryServersDao.java:114)
        at org.artifactory.storage.db.servers.service.ArtifactoryServersServiceImpl.updateArtifactoryServer(ArtifactoryServersServiceImpl.java:85)
        at org.artifactory.lifecycle.storage.db.servers.service.ArtifactoryServersCommonServiceImpl.updateArtifactoryServer(ArtifactoryServersCommonServiceImpl.java:218)
        at org.artifactory.state.ArtifactoryStateManagerUtil.updateArtifactoryServer(ArtifactoryStateManagerUtil.java:75)
        at org.artifactory.state.ArtifactoryStateManagerUtil.createOrUpdateArtifactoryServerState(ArtifactoryStateManagerUtil.java:37)
        at org.artifactory.lifecycle.storage.db.init.PostDbSchemaInitializationManager.createInitialServerState(PostDbSchemaInitializationManager.java:72)
        at org.artifactory.lifecycle.storage.db.init.PostDbSchemaInitializationManager.convertAndInit(PostDbSchemaInitializationManager.java:63)
        at org.artifactory.lifecycle.storage.db.init.HaInitLock.runInsideInitLockIfNeeded(HaInitLock.java:110)
        at org.artifactory.lifecycle.storage.db.init.PostDbSchemaInitializationManager.init(PostDbSchemaInitializationManager.java:50)
        at org.artifactory.lifecycle.webapp.servlet.BasicConfigurationManager.initArtifactoryInstallation(BasicConfigurationManager.java:154)
        at org.artifactory.lifecycle.webapp.servlet.BasicConfigurationManager.initialize(BasicConfigurationManager.java:126)
        at org.artifactory.lifecycle.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryHomeConfigListener.initBasicConfigManager(ArtifactoryHomeConfigListener.java:61)
        at org.artifactory.lifecycle.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryHomeConfigListener.contextInitialized(ArtifactoryHomeConfigListener.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4764)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5222)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:698)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:696)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:689)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1888)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedRead(NioSocketImpl.java:283)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:309)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:803)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:976)
        at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.readMore(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:140)
        at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.ensureBytes(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:109)
        at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.read(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:67)
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.receiveChar(PGStream.java:306)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1952)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:308)
        ... 35 common frames omitted
```

We are using postgresql DB and I can see that artifactory is able to reach it and I see these queries piling up in DB:

```
query            | UPDATE access_configs SET modified = $1,  data = $2  WHERE config_name = $3
```

and

```
    query            | UPDATE artifactory_servers SET start_time = $1, context_url = $2, server_state = $3, server_role = $4, last_heartbeat = $5, artifactory
_version = $6, artifactory_revision = $7, artifactory_release = $8, artifactory_running_mode = $9, license_hash=$10 WHERE server_id = $11
backend_type     | client backend
```

also in DB logs I can see following:

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "access_configs_pk"
DETAIL:  Key (config_name)=(shared.security.joinKey) already exists.
STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO access_configs (config_name, modified, data) VALUES ($1, $2, $3)
```

It seems like the DB get's locked on the initial query or something... is anyone able to see where the exact problem is?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell exactly whats wrong here without the full Artifactory logs. But a few things of note. That error is a warning, would be helpful to see an actual ERROR to be sure of the root problem here.

If you see those queries piling up and not processing, then it sounds like a DB issue.

This Postgres error seems to occur if you are using bad timeouts or other configurations for the DB, see here: [HikariPool-1 - Connection marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08006), ErrorCode(0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60925289/hikaripool-1-connection-marked-as-broken-because-of-sqlstate08006-errorcode)

Sorry I couldn't help more with this, but hope it gives you a start.